# Opening a PNG fails with `cannot identify image file`

Tags: python

I'm trying to open a PNG file with Python.  I do believe I have a properly encoded PNG.

It starts with:

```
\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n\x00\x00\x00\rIHDR
```

And ends with:

```
\x00IEND\xaeB`\x82
```

My code so far:

```
import PIL.Image as Image
with open('./test_image_3.txt', 'rb') as f:
    b = f.read()
    b = base64.b64decode(b).decode("unicode_escape").encode("latin-1")
    b = b.decode('utf-16-le')
    img = Image.open(io.BytesIO(b))
    img.show()

    b = base64.b64decode(b).decode("unicode_escape").encode("latin-1")
```

```
    UnicodeDecodeError: 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 178-179: truncated \uXXXX escape
```

Comment: What's with all the `decode` and `encode`?  Your file isn't base64 encoded, and it's already binary.  Just open it and use it.

Comment: @MarkRansom I tried without decoding but it doesn't work - I get `cannot identify image file`.  A working example would be very much appreciated.

Comment: It looks like that .txt file contains encoded PNG data, but it is NOT base64 encoded. It appears that its data is stored as a Python byte literal. You just have to decode the byte literal string into just plain bytes.

Comment: As a side note to the OP: I strongly recommend that you learn some tool with which you can look at contents of a file and see exactly what bytes it contains. On un*x systems (including Linux and macOS) `od` is usable, albeit a bit primitive.

Comment: Judging by your comments here and on the answer, your file is messed up.  The best course of action would be to write the file in a non-messed up way so you don't have to jury-rig a way to read it.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately I can't read the file you've provided as the website butchered it massively. Either use pastebin or github (or something similar) where it'll be possible to retrieve `text/plain` e.g. via `curl` so I can attempt to reproduce the problem 1:1 for the contents.

However, the general approach would be this:

```py
from PIL import Image

with Image.open("./test_image_3.txt") as im:
    im.show()
```

it's directly from Pillow's [documentation](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html) and it does not care about the file's name or extension.

Alternatively, if you have `open()` call with a file handle:

```py
from PIL import Image

with open("./test_image_3.txt", "rb") as file:
    with Image.open(file) as im:
        im.show()
```

And if you have it mangled somehow, then judging from your `encode()` and `decode()` calls it would be this:

```py
from PIL  import Image
from io import BytesIO

data = <some raw PNG bytes, the original image>

# here I store it in that weird format and write as bytes
with open("img.txt", "wb") as file:
    file.write(data.decode("latin-1").encode("unicode_escape"))

# here I read it back as bytes, reverse the chain of calls and invert
# the call pairs for en/decoding so encode() -> decode() and vice-versa
with open("img.txt","rb") as file:
    content = BytesIO()
    content.write(
        file.read().decode("unicode_escape").encode("latin-1")
    )
    # seek back, so the BytesIO() can return back the full content
    content.seek(0)
    # then simply read as if using a file handle
    with Image.open(content) as img:
        img.show()
```

Comment: Since that .txt file's data is stored as a Python bytes literal string, rather than the bytes themselves, how would this work? The data is literally stored as `\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n\x00\x00\x00\rIHDR`, as in, that's the actual text in the .txt file.

Comment: @RandomDavis Added a case for that as well

Comment: Yes, the file literally contains those characters - it's not mangled.  Trying your suggestions now.

Comment: When trying your last suggestion I get `OSError: unrecognized data stream contents when reading image file`. and if I try the first code I get `PIL.UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file`

Comment: @CaptainB Well, that's the state of the data you have, at least according to the website. In case you have it in a better format, feel free to provide. I got the same message, however I took a proper PNG picture, reversed your code and added how to save and load the contents after that encoding/decoding. Try to upload using https://pastebin.com/

Comment: @CaptainB deleted

Comment: @CaptainB Check [the alternatives](https://alternativeto.net/software/pastebin/) and look for anything that can reproduce the content as raw or `text/plain`.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/bryaan/8b1b5d07efc2454abe19393af8e1577e